# Differentiation between subtypes derived from the same base

Tags: typescript

I've got some code similar to the one below where 2 interfaces are derived from the same base. The function "String" takes an arugment of type "StringAsset". Now if i call the "String" function and pass it a value of "NumberAsset" i expect Typescript to give me a typing error. But that is not the case.

My guess is that the function implicitly takes "BaseAsset" arguments even when explicitly typed to "StringAsset".

How do i enforce subtypes to only accept said subtype and not a sibling type?

```
interface BaseAssets {
    message?: string
}

interface StringAssets extends BaseAssets {
    length?: number
    maxLength?: number
    minLength?: number
}

interface NumberAssets extends BaseAssets {
    value?: number
    maxValue?: number
    minValue?: number
}

function String(assets: StringAssets){
    //Some code to run
}

const asset:NumberAssets = {
    minValue: 10,
    maxValue: 100,
}

String(asset) //Expected typing error
```

Comment: It should work but you actually have to define some properties in `StringAssets` that are not in `NumberAssets`.

Comment: Notice that it is not a good idea to overload [a common API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). It will be hard to understand.

Comment: Is this your [mcve]?  Because those places that say "some more properties" don't have more properties.  Add some and see if that helps.  Also I'd stay away from reusing existing names like [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), which might be an issue.

Comment: Just to lazy to write out properties. But yeah each interface has their own seperate unique properties.  I'll add some for clarity.

the String function is part of a validator and mainly name like since it's going to be validator.String in the end.

Comment: Solved it. Apparently it's a type compatibility case where optional properties are treated as non-existing properties. Thus "BaseAsset", "StringAssets" and "NumberAssets" are structurally the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Typescript treats interfaces with optional properties differently to interfaces with explicit properties. Two subtypes with only optional properties will be structurally equal to it's base type thus treating all 3 equally during type checking.